# What am i doing wrong using grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to use grid and make one big box and two different on the right side of it but it is all scrambled up and as i inspect it it doesn't even show the pattern i'm aiming for. What could be wrong because i think i declared everything right.

I am trying to make 3 columns and 2 rows fill them with 2 columns 2 rows main box and the right side to take up the third column 1 small different box each row. But instead as i am inspecting it i get 5 columns and 2 rows -.-

```css
.top-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "main-box main-box small-box-a"
    "main-box main-box small-box-b";
    grid-template-columns: 200px 50px;
    grid-template-rows: 300px 50px;
}

.main-box {
    grid-area: main-box;
    min-height: 300px;
    background-color: green;
}

.small-box-a {
    grid-area: small-box-a;
}

.small-box-b {
    grid-area: big-box-b;

}
```

```html
<div class="top-container">
  <div class="main-box"> This is a big box </div>
  <div class="small-box-a"> This is a small box A</div>
  <div class="small-box-b"> This is a small box B</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You had a typo..

```
.small-box-b {
    grid-area: big-box-b;

}
```

should be

```
.small-box-b {
    grid-area: small-box-b;

}
```

```css
.top-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "main-box main-box small-box-a" 
  "main-box main-box small-box-b";
  grid-template-columns: 200px 50px;
  grid-template-rows: 300px 50px;
}

.main-box {
  grid-area: main-box;
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}

.small-box-a {
  grid-area: small-box-a;
}

.small-box-b {
  grid-area: small-box-b;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-container">
  <div class="main-box"> This is a big box </div>
  <div class="small-box-a"> This is a small box A</div>
  <div class="small-box-b"> This is a small box B</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I feel so dumb some times. Thank you for your time.